# Graceful HiveQL query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a file with lines like this:

```
232404812.913232|1248|ip:tcp:jxta
232404812.913238|66|ip:udp:data
232404812.913615|98|ip:udp:l2tp:ppp:ip:tcp
```

I executed the following HiveQL commands:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE b_packet (timestamp string, packet_length int, protocol string) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|" 
LOCATION 's3://b-file/input/'; 

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE b_packet_out (protocol string, cnt int) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t" 
LOCATION 's3://b-file/output/1/'; 

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE b_packet_out SELECT 'overall', 
COUNT(*) FROM b_packet GROUP BY protocol; 

INSERT INTO TABLE b_packet_out SELECT 'tcp', 
COUNT(*) FROM b_packet WHERE protocol REGEXP '^ip:tcp'; 

INSERT INTO TABLE b_packet_out SELECT 'udp', 
COUNT(*) FROM b_packet WHERE protocol REGEXP '^ip:udp'; 

INSERT INTO TABLE b_packet_out SELECT 'icmp', 
COUNT(*) FROM b_packet WHERE protocol REGEXP '^ip:icmp';
```

Such that I have the following in the output table.

```
hive> select * from b_packet_out;
OK
udp 2241
overall 10000
icmp    64
tcp 7633
```

Is there a more graceful way for HiveQL queries so I could reduce the number of lines to get the same output ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
count(*) as overall,
sum( if(protocol like '^ip:tcp',1,0) as tcp,
sum( if(protocol like '^ip:udp',1.0) as udp,
sum( if(protocol like '^ip:icmp'1,0) as icmp 
from b_packet
```

This generates the same counts with one pass of the data .

If you have more protocols you can also say
    select
    split(protocol,':')[ 1],
    count(*)
    group by split(protocol,':')[1]
but this won't give the overall counts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different solution, but it makes multiple passes on the data and doesn't really save you on the number of code lines:

```
SELECT          CASE WHEN GROUPING__ID = 0 THEN 'overall' ELSE 
                        CASE WHEN protocol LIKE 'ip:tcp%' THEN 'tcp'
                             WHEN protocol LIKE 'ip:udp%' THEN 'udp'
                             WHEN protocol LIKE 'ip:icmp%' THEN 'icmp'   END  END    AS protocol 
                , COUNT(1)                                                           AS cnt 
FROM            b_packet  
GROUP BY        CASE WHEN protocol LIKE 'ip:tcp%' THEN 'tcp'
                     WHEN protocole LIKE 'ip:udp%' THEN 'udp'
                     WHEN protocol LIKE 'ip:icmp%' THEN 'icmp'   END
GROUPING SETS   (
                    (CASE WHEN protocol LIKE 'ip:tcp%' THEN 'tcp'
                          WHEN protocol LIKE 'ip:udp%' THEN 'udp'
                          WHEN protocol LIKE 'ip:icmp%' THEN 'icmp'  END)
                    , () 
                )
```